# How can I add user information to orders administration pages?

Tags: users, commerce

I'm using [Commerce User Profile Pane](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_user_profile_pane) to capture Drupal Users profile fields *directly* in the Commerce checkout pages : as I have several custom customer fields (birthday, passport number...), I found this more accurate than storing this data in Billing information.

How can I display the collected informations along with the billing information data (name, address), in the order view page : `admin/commerce/orders/%`, and in the quick edit view ?

I can't find any view or .tpl for such task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Andy's advices about [Drupal Theming](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/125082/how-to-theme-commerce-customer-profile#125231), I used [devel_themer](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_themer), and could find immediately the correct template : `commerce_backoffice/theme/commerce-order--backoffice.tpl.php`.